# Basis of very ample line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over field $K$ and $L$ be a very ample line bundle over $X$. Assume that $r=h^0(X,L)$, then can we find $r$ closed points $\{P_1,...,P_r\}$  and a basis $\{s_1,...,s_r\}$ of $H^0(X,L)$ such that $s_i(P_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, just choose points in a general position, and then find sections.

Comment: @Sasha, what do you mean by general position?

Comment: Not three on a line, not four on a plane, etc.

Comment: @Sasha, then how could you get the existence of points in a general position?

Comment: For instance you can argue by induction in dimension. Choose a hyperplane section of $X$, one point away from it, and (by induction) $r-1$ points in general position on the hyperplane section.